# C++, MinGW, Windows: printing numbers using std::cout is painfully slow

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, mingw-w64

I just got a new laptop, and after installing MinGW, the execution time of simple programs is atrocious. Below is a simple for-loop I wrote.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
    {
        cout<<i<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On my laptop with a ryzen 9 4000 cpu running Windows, it took 18.9 seconds to execute. I have tried using different IDEs and reinstalling MinGW, but the same problem still persists.

Any ideas on how to make this run faster?

Comment: Did you turn on optimizations?

Comment: It's all that (essentially unbuffered) output, particularly when the console window needs to scroll. Redirect the output to a file

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573424/c-does-cout-statement-makes-code-slower
Have you tried replacing `endl` with `'\n'`?

Comment: `g++ -O3` and replace `endl` with `\n` - if you use a windows console to run it,  it's that that slows it down though

Comment: Have you tried calling [`std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162367/significance-of-ios-basesync-with-stdiofalse-cin-tienull) right after entering main?

With this, and the other comments so far, it should be fast.

Comment: Compiler flags and micro-optimizations aside, this is **hugely unusual**.  Printing integers 1 to 10000 should **not** take around 20 seconds.  I suspect that some virus scanner or other background process is halting execution and taking the bulk of that time.

Comment: Windows terminals are (or at least used to be) notoriously slow. Flushing after every output doesn't make it any faster.

Comment: @Drew the code (compiled with a very old g++ 4.8 I had around) takes around 7 seconds on the windows command line on my windows 10 machine. Newline instead of flush and no stdio sync reduces it to a few hundred milliseconds, with the sync being the main culprit.

Comment: Do you have an anti-virus program running?  These programs are usually a bane to developers.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thank you for the advice. I ran this with -O3 and it took only a few milliseconds to execute

Answer (score 4):

#### GCC or clang (and thus your setup using MinGW)

Apply the suggestions from the comments:

- Most important: Use [`std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) for the reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162367/significance-of-ios-basesync-with-stdiofalse-cin-tienull). There is synchronization overhead if you don't do this. If you only use c++ streams, which you probably want, you do not need this synchronization. If this is not done, it prevents line buffering, for the reasons given [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio).
- Use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`. [`std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) flushes the stream. This slows it down. (Note: This most likely only has an effect when you redirect the output to a text file. When printing to a terminal, the stream will most likely be line buffered (or maybe completely unbuffered). In this case, it doesn't make a difference, printing a newline will also cause the stream to be flushed)
- Enable `-Og` (optimizations suitable for debugging) or `-O3` (full optimizations) when calling the compiler (see your compilers documentation on optimization, e.g. [this page for GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html))

Then, you get this program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code you posted ran 7 seconds on my windows 10 machine, when printing to the windows command line. This runs in a few (maybe hundred?) milliseconds when compiled without optimizations and in less than 50ms when compiled with optimizations. Most of the change -- for me -- comes from the `sync_with_stdio` call.

#### MSVC

[MSVC has std::cout completely unbuffered by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22633665/extremely-slow-stdcout-using-ms-compiler), even after calling `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);`. Here, it helps to manually set the stream to be line-buffered using (as suggested in the linked post) ([docs for setvbuf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/setvbuf)):

```cpp
setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IOLBF, 4096)
```

Comment: No, this doesn't run any faster. Test it on Windows if you wish. Swapping `endl` with `'\n'` has no difference on Windows if it's actually going to stdout.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out. The solution to this problem for me was to enable the optimization `-O3`